# android webview not calling only peerjs functions

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to use peerjs in android vie webview, but the problem is it not working, when I debugged and tried different approaches I got to know that normal js functions work with no problem, the problem only when I call a function which includes peerjs

permissions i took in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

MAINACTIVITY

here are two buttons 1 calls to simple js function named callJs and other one calls peerjs function named testweb

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Setting Allowed JS Bullet Window
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this),"AndroidFunction");

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webViewTest.html");

    Button webTest1 = findViewById(R.id.webTest1);
    
    //calls normal js function
    webTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:callJS()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    Button webTest2 = findViewById(R.id.webTest2);
    //calls js function with peerjs
    webTest2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:testWeb()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });


}
```

JAVASCRIPTINTERFACE

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
MainActivity mainActivity;
public JavaScriptInterface(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast){
    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

js functions

```
<script src="./peerjs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function callJS() {
    AndroidFunction.showToast("Toast From javascript");
    alert("Android Called JS Of callJS Method");
  }

  function testWeb() {
    alert("testWeb Method called");
    var peer = new Peer(1234, {
      host: "192.168.****",
      port: 8000,
      path: "/strange",
    });

    peer.on("open", () => {
      AndroidFunction.showToast("Toast From testWebPeer");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: well, on some level I solved it but video/audio calling not working, using this method just blank screen.

Comment: I think i have solved this issue by adding two permissions RECORD_AUDIO, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS after this my code worked but I am looking for camera change while ongoing call. so I have asked you here you also need camera permission in app

Comment: I think you can read more about peerjs library for some modifications.

Comment: i have readed all peerjs documentation but there is no function for this but some users are telling that this is possible but not working their solution when I try to implement in my code. so I am asking to all users which has used this lib for android webview

Comment: What about using a different library, if you can implement it.

Comment: yes we can use webrtc in native its very hard to understand and control because there is no good documentation available on any website also it makes app size very huge like nearly adds 15 MB in to our app. on other hand peerjs is based on webview so no need to worry about size

Comment: I was talking about js libraries, there are a lot of Js libraries like peerjs.

Comment: can you please suggest me some of them so I can look in to that also

Comment: I don't have much experience in it so I don't know which of them is best still, you can google "peerjs alternative" I heard that simple-peer is also good.

Comment: hey, @gulabpatel if possible could please you share your repository link of this app. because audio/video is not working in my app even after giving all permissions.